# Ionic 3 build error: "No server to serve request"

Tags: angularjs, ionic3, android-build

I ran this command:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

And I received this error:

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs
>   for details. :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No  server to serve request. Check logs
>   >     for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: what is the command you tried to execute?

Comment: ionic cordova build android

Comment: what is the latest android sdk & cordova version installed within your system?

Comment: @Saifkhan Did you find any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just comment these line of code in your app build.gradle file

```
// compileOptions {
    //     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    //     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    // }
```

Re-run the command it will build successfully.